# Conflict between cron.deny and allow who wins?

Tags: cron

which one wins in conflict deny or allow?  Is the behavior the same for hosts.allow and all the other similar files?

Answer (score 1):

From `man cron` (my emphasis):

> Running cron jobs can be allowed or disallowed for different users.   For  this  purpose, use  the  cron.allow  and cron.deny files.  **If the cron.allow file exists**, a user must be listed in it to be allowed to use cron[.] **If the cron.allow file  does  not  exist  but  the cron.deny  file does exist**, then a user must not be listed in the cron.deny file in order to use cron.  **If neither of these files exists**, only the super user  is  allowed  to  use cron.

These seem to be the only options. In other words, it seems at most one of `cron.allow` and `cron.deny` should exist, so it's probably implementation dependent. It is interesting that the manual says "use  the  cron.allow  **and** cron.deny files," which seems to counteract the rest of the paragraph.